# how to refer individually several auto-generated textarea having same name

Tags: html, jsp, model-view-controller, jstl, el

As in the below code, textarea gets generated based on how many items criteriaList return. Suppose it returns 5 items, so 5 textarea gets generated. But all of them will have the same name as 'comment'. My problem is I want to refer to the value of each of them seperately, so that I can manipulate and store in DB. How do I refer them ?

```
<c:forEach var="criteria" items="${criteriaList}">
<tr>
<td><textarea name="comment" class="txt" rows="6" cols="25" ></textarea></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

For the reading part am using the following :-

```
@RequestMapping(value="findEmployees.htm", params="searchType=startReview")
public ModelAndView onSubmitSearchByName(
@RequestParam("assComment") String comment){
List<Criteria> criteriaList = criteriaService.getReviewCriteria(phase);

ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
boolean check = reviewService.addReview(release, ir, stream, application, phase, sub, reviewer, complexity);
mav.addObject("criteriaList", criteriaList);
mav.setViewName("find/sqaStartDetails");
return mav;
}
```

How to implement the id concept in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a great solution for this. Check out [AutoPopulatingList](http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=12).

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

Add an `Id` property to each `textarea`:

```
<textarea name="comment" class="txt" rows="6" cols="25" id="SOMEVALUEHERE" >
```

Then you can use the `Id` property later to associate each `textarea` with a given comment...

The `Id` you can get from the `criteria` var or from a simple counter.

Answer (score 0):

u must use an id like

```
<c:forEach var="criteria" items="${criteriaList}">
<tr>
<td><textarea name="comment<%=criteria.id%>" class="txt" rows="6" cols="25" ></textarea></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

for reading

```
request.getParamerter("comment"+id)
```

Comment: The id one is working. But for the reading part I am not sure what to do. Please check my comment below.

Comment: I have added my comments for the reading part in my question. And yeah thanks a lot. :)